# Disabling/hiding shopping cart for a logged in customer

Tags: magento-1.8, php

I'd like to set a login for a customer where he/she, can just surf through the products but cannot check out.

Is it possible in Magento ver. 1.8.1.0?

Comment: How about the guest? If yes, I'd suggest you to disable Mage_Checkout completely.

Comment: Yes I'd though so, however we don't wan't it for all the users who visits website and besides hiding shopping cart for all the potential guest users would be unhealthy for the business. So, is it possible to get it done for a specific user or group of users (who are logged in?)

Comment: You can try this: https://github.com/riconeitzel/PaymentFilter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found it through tech support,

After user has been registered on the site. You have to go to admin panel -> Customers -> Select the customer -> Account Information -> Role -> Select Advisory Member instead of Full Member. Then that user won't be able to access SC.